# Sticky footer overflow issue?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I am having some trouble with my sticky footer. First of all, my content does not reach the entire bottom of the screen (even underneath the footer .. check on larger monitor). Also, when the window is smaller than the content, the header moves and does not expand 100% in width when you move the horizontal scrollbar. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my testing site: [My Site](http://fear.novaprogramming.com)

If you use firebug or Google Chrome's built in Inspect Element, you can see where all the elements are.

Here is some of the css:

```
.content
{
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    background:#222;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom:50px; /* Padding for footer (width) */
}

.contentInner
{
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000; /* So you can see it */
}
```

Here is what it looks like when the content is bigger than the window: [image]

I would also like the Content to extent all the way down the page with the content!

Comment: You can't use height 100% without absolute positioned div. And even then you will not have wanted results.

Comment: Then how would i achieve what i am going for?

Comment: @Hardy I am wanting the content, the dark background to extend all the way down with the footer.

Comment: You should then add bottom padding to your content or position your content absolute.

Comment: Or change your content height with javascript.

Comment: @Hardy Non of the below solutions do anything. So i am very confused about how to do this.

Comment: Can you post screenshot?

Comment: @FarwallGhost Yep, i just did.

Comment: I'll create some example for you soon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit / add your css like this to get rid of smaller screen issues..

```
.mainContainer {
  min-width: 1100px;
}
```

To get that content background to continue all way down, i suggest using centered background image in `.mainContainer` and remove content background OR just set `.content` `min-height` to some large value like 900px OR use javascript to set content height if smaller than screen height.

Comment: That still does not work. When i mean by the screen issues, make the window smaller and then move the horizontal scrollbar. The header moves and the background shows. That is not what i want.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong.. of course header moves when you scroll horizontally.. i tested and it looks just fine. Just add that min-width with/to your other css in that class..

Comment: Yes, that is the issue i need fixed.

Comment: If your header is wider than screen of course it scrolls!! It is normal!! If it won't scroll people can't use it.. ok.. if i make my browser screen 200px wide, how can i use menu if header won't scroll..?

Comment: No, i want it to scroll, BUT i do not want it to scroll MORE than the header width, so you do not see the body.

Answer (score 0):

if you put your `.mainContainer` to the width of your `.content`, it will work.

```
.mainContainer {
    width: 1100px;
}
```

Is it what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CSS to this one.

```
.content
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    background:#222;
    min-height: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    position:absolute;
}

.contentInner
{
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    min-height: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: That does nothing but mess up my css.